Prevent posts assigned to sub-categories being accessible also through top category URL
I have set up a fresh WordPress setup and added three categories. For the sake of my question, let's say that the top-catgory is named "World" and the two sub-categories are "Germany" and "USA".
Now I have added a new blog post and assigned it to the subcategory "URL", so the blog post is accessible through www.mysite.tld/World/USA/my-first-post/ . That's fine.
However, I can also access the same post by www.mysite.tld/World/my-first-post/ . This is not intended behavior, of course. On the editor, only the subcategory has been checked.
I never noticed this before. Unfortunately, I haven't found any information about. So could it be a theme related issue?
Anyway, how can I prevent the blog posts of sub-categories are also being accessible through their main category URL?
Any help is highly appreciated.
Tobias

no that's how hierarchical terms are supposed to work! It's best not to think of sub-categories as a box of posts that's connected to the parent, but instead as a smaller box inside of the parent. Afterall if you had a "Europe" and "North America" term you'd want them to show everything in countries on those continents! On WP_Term_Query the parameter you'd want is include_children but I don't know off the top of my head how to apply that to the main query cleanly via pre_get_posts without creating a whole new one which carries its own problems

Sorry for my late reply. Thanks for your notes, Tom. I'll look deeper into this. Anyway, for me this is quite an unexpected behaviour, especially considering search engine optimization matters.
